# How to get @ mentions in PrimeNg Editor (Quill + quill-mention in Angular)

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

Im tasked with implementing a mentions feature to our text editors. I am using PrimeNg Editor which is built on Quill. I found the package  [quill-mention](https://github.com/afry/quill-mention) which seems like it can help solve this. I am not sure how to configure this in the primeng editor component. I see there is a `getQuill()` function that may be helpful, I am just not sure how. Thanks!

I am okay with actually utilizing the module and passing it users etc, it is more just allowing my editor to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Import quill-mention into component

```
import Mention from 'quill-mention'
```

Create HTML

```
<p-editor #editor></p-editor>
```

Create instance of Editor

```
@ViewChild('editor', { static: true }) editor: Editor;
```

Finally add below add

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
// init instance
const quilInstance = this.editor.getQuill();
new Mention(quilInstance, {
  mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
  source: function (searchTerm: string, renderList: (data: any, searchText: string) => void, mentionChar: string) {
    // sample data set for displaying
    // enter your logic here
    const items = [{ id: 1, value: 'Partha' }]
    renderList(items, searchTerm);
  }
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `onInit` event to get the editor and configure it.

In the template:

```
<p-editor (onInit)="editorOnInit($event)"></p-editor>
```

And in the Typescript class:

```js
editorOnInit(event: any) {
    const quillInstance = event.editor;
    new Mention(quillInstance, options);
}
```

Where `options` can be like in Partha Ranjan's answer.